# Regex is working in presto SQL but is not working in pyspark expr

Tags: sql, regex, pyspark, presto

Data:

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |filters                                                      |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"option.p.one":["A","B","C","D"], "option.p.type_two":["1"]}|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Code to generate data:

```
columns = ["id","filters"]
data = [(1, '{"option.p.one":["A","B","C","D"], "option.p.type_two":["1"]}')]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

I have two regex written to extract and store the key and values of this string.

1. Keys: `\.([a-z_]+)\":'`
2. Values: `:\[([^:]+)\`

Now, when I run the following code, I see that my values regex does not return the intended results.

```
dfFromRDD2.withColumn("filter_category", expr(f"regexp_extract_all(filters, '\.([a-z_]+)\":', 1)"))\
.withColumn("filter_inputs", expr(f"regexp_extract_all(filters, ':\[([^:]+)\]', 0)")).show(truncate = False)


+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
|id |filters                                                      |filter_category|filter_inputs|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
|1  |{"option.p.one":["A","B","C","D"], "option.p.type_two":["1"]}|[one, type_two]|[:[, :[]     |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Both regex work fine in Presto SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in the python string eg.

```py
dfFromRDD2.withColumn("filter_category", expr(f"regexp_extract_all(filters, '\\\.([a-z_]+)\\\":', 1)"))\
.withColumn("filter_inputs", expr(f"regexp_extract_all(filters, ':\\\[([^:]+)\\\]', 0)")).show(truncate = False)
```

Let me know if the above works for you.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Can you elaborate on why this works in Presto vs Python?

Comment: In presto, you would be running the query with the pattern as is. What I've found in my experience and as you can see, it is easy to reproduce, with pyspark, the `\\` character has to be escaped as `\\\` also so that the intended escape character (eg `\.` or `\[`) is not escaped before being sent to the execution engine. Maybe `\\\[` as input becomes `\\[` then `\[` during escapes. I am not sure whether this behaviour is a result of the py4j but that may be a good S/O question to ask separately to explain the internals of passing regex through different impl eg (python/scala)